# What is the running time for Flatten a LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, big-o, singly-linked-list

I had the next problem:

[image]

My first thought was: the time complexity solution must be O(n) because needs to be traversed at least once.

However, in my current solution I'm using two while bucles. I think this doesn't necessarily means is exponential O(n^2). Can you provide me an idea of why this solution is still linear even if I set two bucles?

```
class Node {
    int value;
    Node next;
    Node child;

    public Node(int val) {
        this.value = val;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node head = generateInput1();
        flattenLinkedList(head);
        traverseLinkedList(head);
    }

    private static Node generateInput1() {
        Node n1 = new Node(1);
        Node n2 = new Node(2);
        Node n3 = new Node(3);
        Node n4 = new Node(4);
        Node n5 = new Node(5);
        Node n6 = new Node(6);
        Node n7 = new Node(7);
        Node n8 = new Node(8);
        Node n9 = new Node(9);

        n1.next = n2;
        n2.next = n3;
        n3.next = n4;
        n5.next = n6;

        n2.child = n5;
        n4.child = n7;
        n5.child = n8;
        n7.child = n9;

        return n1;
    }

    public static Node flattenLinkedList(Node head) {
        Node current = head;
        Node tail = findTail(head);

        while (current != null) {
            if (current.child != null) {
                Node head2 = current.child;
                current.child = null;
                tail.next = head2;
                tail = findTail(head2);
            }

            current = current.next;
        }

        return head;
    }

    private static Node findTail(Node x) {
        if (x == null) return x;

        while (x.next != null) {
            x = x.next;
        }
        return x;
    }

    private static void traverseLinkedList(Node h) {
        while (h != null) {
            System.out.print(h.value + " -> ");
            h = h.next;
        }
        System.out.print("NULL");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: If you are allowed to use linear space, you should be able to do it in linear time complexity.

Comment: Your "current solution" is not a solution at all. The result is not sorted.

Comment: @DavidChoweller I don't think so. In the worst case where it branches every node, you will have to do log(n) comparisons, making it n*log(n) right?

Comment: I've changed my mind.  I think the solution does work.  The main loop in `flattenLinkedList` traverses the whole list, so that's on the order of n.  There are also sub-traversals of the list by `findTail` but in total they don't exceed `n`.  So, I think the entire algorithm is linear and uses only constant space for the `head2`, `current` and `tail` pointers.

Comment: The algorithm avoids using a queue by setting last `next` pointer of the list as it is being built to the node that needs to be processed after the current list is done with.